# Why does this React/Redux code typecheck with a seemingly undefined variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In [the connected components section of the Redux "writing tests" guide](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/WritingTests.md), there's a test-utils.js file (copied below):

```js
// test-utils.js
import React from 'react'
import { render as rtlRender } from '@testing-library/react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

function render(
  ui,
  {
    initialState,
    store = createStore(reducer, initialState),
    ...renderOptions
  } = {}
) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>
  }
  return rtlRender(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions })
}

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react'
// override render method
export { render }
```

It seems like this file is standalone. If we look at the arguments to `render`, we see `store = createStore(reducer, initialState)`, which typechecks (!), despite `reducer` not being defined elsewhere. I can understand why `initialState`, `store`, `renderOptions` are "allowed to be undefined" (because they're arguments to the function!), but does this "propagate" to `createStore`? If so, how, and what is this behavior called?

Comment: Looks like an oversight to me, really.  Probably needs to be edited to pull that from somewhere.